# How to add x amount of employees to a stationlog?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, erd

[image: ERD]

I have an ERD.
The Stationlog table logs which employee worked at the station and at what time the employee logged in and out. The station produces orders.
As of now there can only be 1 employee logged in at a station but I am trying to figure out how I can have multiple employees in a stationlog. I want one Employee to be the manager within that Stationlog and give him the ability to add an infinite amount of employees to that stationlog.

I have tried adding fields such as employee1, employee2, employee3 in the Stationlog (not shown in this ERD) but that means I cannot add an infinite amount of employees to each stationlog.

How would I be able for one manager (who is an employee) to be able to add x amount of employees to 1 Stationlog?

Comment: Why does your station log not handle it?  You can have infinite in there?

Comment: Because every stationlog marks a session worked at a station. I don't want to make a new stationlog for every employee, I want multiple employees in one stationlog.

Comment: Dont have employees in the station log then, have StationLogEmployees maybe and have StationLogID and EmployeeIDs

Comment: That's a good solution. I will do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your current design is that one specific `Stationlog` row refers to exactly one `Station` and one `Employee`.  Another `Employee` for the same `Station` would imply that there's a different `Stationlog` row for that other employee.  (hopefully not overlapping with the first). Nothing prevents 10 employees working at the same time on the same station, each with a different log entry.

If this is not sufficient, and you want one employee define the "session" with login and logout time but allow several employees on that log,  you'd need to make the relation `Stationlog >o----|< Employee` many-to-many.

Of couse many-to-many is easily drawn on the diagram, but would require an association table for its implementation to hold the valid pairs.

```
Stationlog >o------   Logteam  ----|<  Employee
                   ------------
                   StationlogID
                   Employee
                   (OrderOfArrival etc...)
```

In `Logteam` you'd put everything which is specific go a given session and a given employee, such as arrival/departure, if this could be different from login/logout.  If managers are predefined,  you'd put a `IsManager` flag in `Employee` table.  But if it's dynamic,  e.g. the first who come (or has the key for the station),  then you'd put this flag in this association table as well